# Using Scrapy's LinkExtractor

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to extract all links from a page using Scrapy, but am struggling to use the LinkExtractor. I've tried the following:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Funda.items import FundaItem

class FundaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Funda"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"
    ]
    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

My understanding is that including `LinkExtractor()` as a `Rule` should make the `response` contain only links. However, if I view the `amsterdam.html` file thus generated, it still seems to contain the entire web page, not just the links.

How can I get the `response` to contain just the links?

Comment: _How can I get the response to contain just the links?_ I don't understand your question. A few things: [link extractors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) are used to extract links from responses. `LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)` returns `Link` objects (with a `.url` attribute). Link extractors, within `Rule` objects, are intended for `CrawlSpider` subclasses, so that the spider follows links, but you get pages in `response` in your callback, not the URLs.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll try to explain: the main page in `start_urls` contains links to pages of individual houses for sale. Ultimately I'd like to open the pages on the individual houses and extract data from them. The documentation mentions that `extract_links` returns a list of `scrapy.link.Link` objects. As I understand from https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/link.py#L8, the `Link` class has `url`, `text`, `fragment`, and `nofollow` attributes, but how might I proceed to get the full `response` from each link?

Comment: You have to generate `Request` object with URL. Scrapy understands only `Request`s. `Link` objects themselves are just holder of URL information (no callback, no headers etc.). So at some point you need to `return scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=......)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would you think it would contain only links?

I think you are misunderstanding the `CrawlSpider` and the `rule` argument. Within `rule` you actually specify crawling logic rather than parsing logic. Parsing is being handled in the function specified the `callback`.

So if you want to you want to save only the links from the response you'd have to extract them from response first. You can even use the same `LinkExtractor`

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    le1 = LinkExtractor()
    rules = (
        Rule(le1, callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # this will give you Link objects
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)
        # this will give you html nodes of <a> 
        links = response.xpath("//a").extract()
```

Comment: Thanks Granitosaurus. As a follow-up question, I'd also like to 'inspect' the output in `links`. I've tried `for link in links:`, `item=FundaItem()`, `item['title'] = link.extract()`, `yield item` and then tried to run scrapy with output as `scrapy crawl Funda -o funda.csv`. However, the .csv file thus generated is empty. How can I use the `links` generated by the first method?

Comment: @khpeek Does your spider return any items? what does the log stay at the end of the crawl? i.e. "'item_scraped_count': 1"?